# Iframe scrolling iOS 8

Tags: iframe, scroll, overflow, ios8

I have an iframe and i need it to have a scrolling overflow. it seems work out in desktop,  i used a work around to make it work in iOS. it works on  android and iOS now. however, iOS8 it fails.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      .scroll-container {
       overflow: scroll;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
     #iframe_survey {
      height: 100%;
     }

    .scroll-container {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: scroll;
     }
   </style>

   <div class="scroll-container scroll-ios">
   <iframe id="iframe_survey" src="www.iframe.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%"></iframe>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Have the same problem, the iOS8 messed something really bad

Comment: Is it safari or a UIWebView app?

Comment: safari for iOS8 @ReigoHein

Comment: chrome for iOS8 seems to have the same problem

Comment: I had the same issue and what worked for me is giving the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch to dom element. Also I did some manipulations for the element height. I had to give the element height explicitly using jquery. If you can provide us with a fiddle, I can help you fix it.

Comment: We solved it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738764/ios8-safari-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-issue/26743685#26743685

Answer (score 36):

Use the code in this way

```
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:600px" src="www.iframe.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the better solution, for me it's working in ios8, but it may have rendering problems when iframe height is bigger than body height. See here for a more detailed explanation: http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/

Comment: The basic difference is using `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:scroll`? That's not working for me.

Answer (score 35):

In order to make an iframe scrollable on iOS, you have to add the CSS3 property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to the parent container:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
  <iframe src="./yxz" style="width:100%;height:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks! However, I had to use a reduced height `<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 99%; border: none;">` to avoid a second scrollbar in my browser (Chrome 71)

Answer (score 6):

I finally got mine working after many hours and testing. Basically what worked for me was this (shown as inline styling to demo).
Making the outer div overflow auto keeps it from displaying an extra set of scrollbars on desktops.

```
<div style="overflow: auto!important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;"> 
   <iframe src="http://www.mywebsiteurl.com" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; display: block; overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: "Making the outer div overflow auto keeps it from displaying an extra set of scrollbars on desktops." And here's point, thank you!
For me, actually, `overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on the wrapper and `display: block` on the iframe was enough.

Answer (score 3):

it did not work for me! but I could figure out a little trick after reading this post: 
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/scrolling-iframe-on-ipad/

Just put an !important after that and works just fine!

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
overflow-y: scroll !important;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that fixes 1 and 2 work on iOS 11, but I also found that in loading a responsive page into the iframe, `overflow-x: hidden;` was also needed to keep the iframe from moving left and right on scroll y attempts. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in iOS 8 that breaks scrolling all together when -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch has been applied to anything that is overflown.

Have a look at the issue I posted a few weeks ago:
[-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; breaks in Apple's iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176288/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-in-apples-ios8)

Answer (score 1):

The must is define your `scroll-container` to `fixed` for the **div** is a fullscreen size. Then inside the **iframe** create a main content who have a properties scrolling.

Inside you iframe, in the `mainContainer-scroll`, you can add:

- `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`     //For active smooth scroll
- `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`   //For material acceleration
- `overflow-y:scroll;`                        //For add scrolling in **y** axis
- `position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;` //For fix the container

**Main page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #iframe_survey {
                height: 100%;
            }

            .scroll-container {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position:fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="scroll-container scroll-ios">
            <iframe id="iframe_survey" src="www.iframe.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Inside Iframe**

```
<div class="mainContainer-scroll" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div class="Content" style="height:2000px;width:100%;background:blue;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what is on the other end of "www.iframe.com"...but for me, in that file's css I added:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That fixed it.

Comment: yes, that fixes it if you have access to the iframe css. if you dont. there's still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use on body style or
overflow:scroll;

Or also use

```
<div style="width:100%;height:600px;overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
<iframe style="overflow:scroll;" src="www.iframe.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make an iframe scroll in iOS by placing an `iframe` inside a `div` (which acts as container) and apply the styles as follows and this works perfectly.

```
.iframe {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}

.div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

As i am working in GWT, for GWT people here is the suggestion.
  In case of GWT just place an iframe in ScrollPanel (div) and apply the styles as above.

Comment: welcome@user3548310, for your next post i recommand you to read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help