# iPad sometimes rubberbands with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, touch, mobile-safari

Take this markup, stick it in an html file, and view it in mobile Safari on an iPad. I'm using an iPad Mini 4 on iOS 9.3.2.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>long</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

</head>
<body style="background-color: #112FCB">  
    <div id="viewport" style="height: 928px; width: 768px; margin-top: 0px; display: block;">
        <div style="width: 638.3376623376623px; height: 771.3246753246754px; transform: scale(1.203125, 1.203125); background-position-x: 0px;">
            <div class="page-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; position: relative;">
                <div class="page-scroll" style="height: 10202px; width: 640px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 254px; top: 259px; width: 88px; height: 89px; display: block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                        <span style="top:-3px;left:0px;">1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 252px; top: 1098px; width: 113px; height: 60px; display: block; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">`
                        <span style="top:-3px;left:0px;">2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 229px; top: 1821px; width: 88px; height: 89px; display: block; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                        <span style="top:-3px;left:0px;">3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 253px; top: 2503px; width: 88px; height: 89px; display: block; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                        <span style="top:-3px;left:0px;">4</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically we have 4 absolutely positioned divs for showing where you are on the page, inside a very tall div (`.page-scroll`), which is inside a relatively positioned div with `overflow-y: scroll` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` (`.page-container`). The other parent divs (`page-viewport` and `viewport`) are there to ensure a consistent look across devices.

On every other device we've tried, swiping to scroll scrolls the page-scroll div inside the page-container div as expected. However, on iPad, we are seeing non-deterministic behavior. If you swipe quickly, the page scrolls normally, but if you swipe slowly, the page will sometimes rubberband. It's as if the `touchstart` event is getting sent to one of the parent divs, and so the iPad thinks it is at the bottom or top of the page.

However! If `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is removed from the `.page-container` div, the problem disappears. But you lose momentum scrolling, which sucks. I should also note that if this markup is loaded onto a page via an iframe, the problem goes away, but that is not really an option for us (because reasons).

I have tried the suggestion in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176288/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-in-apples-ios8) to put yet another div inside `.page-scroll` and set `height: calc(100% + 1px)`, but that did not fix the bug.

I do see a lot of related questions that indicate `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` has a myriad of problems, but none of those questions are quite exactly this bug, I think.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: You can try this [API](https://github.com/lazd/iNoBounce). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though!