# Enable touch scrolling for mobile view, Bokeh app

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, bokeh

I have a web app, created using [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) and hosted on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). I recently created a mobile style for the app, viewable here:

https://btac-web-plots.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker-mobile

However, when viewed on an iOS mobile device, the single-finger touch scrolling does not work. As a hack work-around, I set `width: 95%` in the `.invcontent-wrapper` tag of my html file (`index.html`). This exposes a vertical strip of the background on the right side where the touch scrolling is functional, acting like a traditional scroll bar. I also added up and down arrows to the vertical strip to direct users to use it as a scroll bar.

How can I enable touch scrolling for the entire screen? The issue may be that the returned Bokeh Document does not allow for touch scrolling interaction...?

I am using the [directory format](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) in Bokeh (utilizing the Bokeh server), where my `index.html` Jinja template file contains the following relevant sections:

css:

```
        {% if display_style|string() == "snowpacktracker-mobile" %}
          <style>
            html {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
            body {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              margin: auto;
              background-color: lightgray;
              overflow-y: scroll;
              -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
              float: left;
            }
           .invcontent-wrapper {
             padding: 0px;
             min-height: 200px;
             width: 95%; /*allows for exposed background on the side*/
             position: relative;
            }
            container { /*this holds arrows so the user knows to scroll*/
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .a { /*up arrow*/
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
              border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
              display: inline-block;
              padding: 3px;
              position: fixed;
              top: 20px;
              right: 1.5%;
              transform: rotate(-135deg);
              -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
            }
            .b { /*down arrow*/
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
                border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 3px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 40px;
                right: 1.5%;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            }
          </style>        
        {% endif %}
```

html:

```
        {% if display_style|string() == "snowpacktracker-mobile" %}
          <div class="invcontent-wrapper"  id="tbc-id">
            {{ plot_div|indent(8) }} 
            {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
          </div>
          <div id="container">
            <div class="a"></div>
            <div class="b"></div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
```

The `id="tbc-id"` is referring to the javascript loading spinner I am using (`var target = document.getElementById('tbc-id');`).

Although a secondary problem, I am also unable to zoom in using the two-finger pinch-out zoom gesture on iOS.

Comment: Single finger scrolling (in graph area of the screen) is not working even on Android phones.

Comment: UPDATE: Since updating my Bokeh version to 1.3.4, all touch features are working for mobile devices! Not sure what specific version of Bokeh included these updates, but this issue is now resolved, making most of the details of this question now irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

The bug certainly comes from the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property. You are not the only one experiencing problems with it:

> Since updating to IOS8, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` stops you being able to scroll whatsoever, and the only way I have been able to fix this so far is by removing `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`
>
> *[-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; breaks in Apple's iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176288/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-in-apples-ios8)*

However, in the [Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-overflow-scrolling), Apple seems to say that it is supported on iOs 5.0 **and later**:

> **Availability:**
>   Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> **Support Level:**
>   Under development

**But**, we can see in the MDN reference:

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be **large incompatibilities between implementations** and **the behavior may change in the future**.
>
> *[-webkit-overflow-scrolling - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)*

### TL;DR

This is not a coding problem, it comes from this non-standard CSS style. Try removing it and see below on how to enhance scrolling.

Did I helped?

---

Here are some other references:

- [WebKit-only properties - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions)
- [-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; breaks in Apple's iOS8 - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176288/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-breaks-in-apples-ios8)

  > The solution I found was to remove all the CSS that tricks the browser into using the GPU:

  ```
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  ```

Comment: Thanks much for this insight. I am on the road right now and won't have time to sit down and try your suggestions for a few days. However, upvote and bounty award for the answer! I will accept once I have a chance to get into my code and try to implement your suggested changes.

Comment: After extensive experimentation using your suggestions and various other potential solutions in the linked references, I am still without touch scrolling capability. I believe the issue is with the Bokeh framework, where returned plot elements do not allow scrolling from within the plot window.

Comment: UPDATE: Since updating my Bokeh version to 1.3.4, all touch features are working for mobile devices! Not sure what specific version of Bokeh included these updates, but this issue is now resolved, making most of the details of this question now irrelevant.