# when I use iframe in ion-content, the ion-content scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, iframe

```
<ion-view view-title="title">
  <ion-content scroll="true">
    <iframe src="{{link}}"></iframe>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

look at the code above.

as the title says,when I use a iframe in the ion-content the scroll does't work.

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug on ios. I have resolved this problem. Refer to the following

[Iframe scrolling iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046373/iframe-scrolling-ios-8)

Answer (score 16):

Use overflow-scroll to enable scrolling

```
<ion-view view-title="title">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
         <iframe src="{{link}}"></iframe>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css to the parent div of iframe

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
overflow: scroll !important;
```

**Exmaple:**

HTML

```
<ion-content class="iframe-fix">
  <iframe [src]="pageUrl" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS

```
.platform-ios{
    .iframe-fix{
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
      overflow: scroll !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

```
<ion-view title="sample page">
 <ion-content>
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
       <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</ion-content>
<ion-view>
```

it will work scroll option is default true.no need to add specifically

Comment: thank you for your answer. but the problem is not caused by browser does not support iframe. The page iframe loaded can be dispalyed.

Comment: <p>  </p> tag is just sample tex to show in iframe it will work fine.i have done so i posted here.if you use iframe in ion-content it works .