# iOS scrollable iFrame

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

Since iOS4 there was a bug that an iFrame could not be scrolled:

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe style="height:100px;border: 1px solid blue" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height:200px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will notice that the `height:100px` style is ignored by iOS.

Is there an official bug ticket for this behaviour?

Is it possible in iOS10 to scroll the content of an iframe?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046373/iframe-scrolling-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 <div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
   <iframe style="height:100px;border: 1px solid blue" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the iframe doesn't get scrollable but the div around it.
Sticky elements are still not sticky to the iframe