# Restrict CSS applying on a particular div

Tags: html, css, scope

I am making a web application through which user can create an email campaign.

While creating the campaign, the user adds email content using [CKEditor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor). He/she can add internal CSS and JavaScript. Once the campaign is created, it looks like the image given below.

I have to show the email content preview in div `#email_content` exactly how it will appear. But common CSS written for the page is applied to `#email_content` and vice-versa. I don't have access to modify the common CSS.

---

How can I show the *email_content* preview exactly how it will appear?

Note: I know using `iframe` for email_content. It is possible, but I am looking for another workaround.

[image: Single Campaign Page]

Comment: Make your page content css very specific so it only targets the elements you want and not the ones in the preview panels - eg use selectors that target ids rather than selectors that target elements.  Ps is it a good idea to allow users to add their own css?  Do they have good knowledge of the css that is available for email clients - ie it won't appear as it would on a normal webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem that does not (yet) have a simple, universal solution.

### Shadow DOM

Ideally you would use Shadow DOM, as it is specifically intended to solve such a problem:

> Shadow DOM provides encapsulation for DOM and CSS in a Web Component.
> Shadow DOM makes it so these things remain separate from the DOM of
> the main document. You can also use Shadow DOM by itself, outside of a
> web component.
>
> Why would you want to keep some code separate from the rest of the
> page? One reason is that on a large site, for example, if the CSS is
> not carefully organized, the styling for the navigation can "leak"
> into the main content area where it was not intended to go, or
> vice-versa. As a site or an app scales, this kind of thing becomes
> difficult to avoid.

- [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM)
- [Also See](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom)

[Shadow DOM is well-supported as of 2022](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1).

### Iframes

On the other end of the spectrum is an `iframe`. `iframes` are supported everywhere, but may require a larger change to the page than you are able to make. More importantly, `iframes` introduce [undesirable scrolling behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046373/453277) on iOS that may change from version to version.

### Targeted Reset

A practical, though not foolproof, solution is to create a CSS reset that only targets the content you want isolated.

```css
/* The start of a simple reset */
#email_content * {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is one of the cases where it may be required to mark a rule as `!important`.

### Targeted Unset (all/initial/unset)

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Answer (score 2):

As it is explained in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-encapsulation-semantic-markup/), you can create a shadow [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) element, in other words encapsulate your element to have its own CSS as it is shown here..

The outside CSS class will not affect your shadow DOM element..

```js
if (! Element.prototype.createShadowRoot && Element.prototype.webkitCreateShadowRoot) {
  Element.prototype.createShadowRoot = Element.prototype.webkitCreateShadowRoot;
}

var div = document.querySelector('#for-shadow');
var fileTemplate = document.getElementById("file-template");
var shadowDom = div.createShadowRoot();
shadowDom.appendChild(fileTemplate.content);
```

```css
.outside{
    background: red;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside inside">from outside</div>
<div id="for-shadow">
<template id="file-template">
  <style>
    .inside{
      color:blue;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    console.log('its js code');
  </script>
  <div class="outside inside">
    this is the div inside the template
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is what I got running this piece of code:

{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: div.createShadowRoot is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 21
}

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```css
#email_content * {
    all: unset;
}
```

This will reset all global CSS, and after that, you can use inline CSS.

Comment: And what if I have to use internal CSS in `#email_content` also?

Comment: Internal CSS not working with this, you have to use inline CSS