# Scrollable iFrame with position:sticky element in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iframe, webkit

I want to create an scrollable iFrame with a `position:sticky` element inside, that also works on iOS.

iOS does not respect the iFrames `height:340px` setting, a **workaround** to still make it scrolling is a container div with `overflow-y:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` (see [Iframe scrolling iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046373/iframe-scrolling-ios-8)).

But when only the outside div is scrolling the `position:sticky` is not working. Is there any other solution to making the iFrame scrollable?

See here on web browser vs. iOS:
https://codepen.io/arichter83/project/full/ZWGEaL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution - wrapping all iFrame content makes the div container obsolete:

```
#wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix